# Angular Bootstrap UI rating system - Changing max value using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ngmodel

I've created a rating system using Angular-UI.
The number of stars displayed come from a variable called max. I'm able to show this variable inside an input using ng-model, but once I modify it, it won't change the number of stars.

You can see what I mean in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQm0DSv1Hn9NmeFV7r7k?p=preview).

Here's the relevant js:

```js
.directive('myRating', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div> \
         <div class="row rating" ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl"> \
           <rating value="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly" state-on="\'glyphicon-star rated\'" state-off="\'glyphicon-star\'"></rating> <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="editStars = !editStars"></a>\
            <input ng-if="editStars" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="max" /> \
         </div> \
      </div>',
    replace: true,
  };
});

var RatingDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.rate = 0;
  $scope.max = 10;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  };
};
```

The `ng-model` is working correctly as it will show the value of max every time, but it won't modify it in real time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally doable. Copy down the ui-bootstrap code and alter it a little bit. I hacked inside and it seems to be working great. Check out a working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/cfHYO4eSndylvS1Mndcn?p=preview). Here are the changes I made, they can be seen on lines 2493-2559.

First I went into the directive and added maxRange as a two-way bound object

```
scope: {
  value: '=',
  onHover: '&',
  onLeave: '&',
  maxRange: '=max'
},
```

Then I went into the controller and changed a few things so I could watch the maxRange value and update the objects based on that.

```
$scope.$watch('maxRange', function() {
  $scope.range = createRateObjects(new Array(parseInt($scope.maxRange)));
});
```

Hacking rocks. Don't be afraid to modify other people's code a little bit if it doesn't fit your needs!

Comment: @EricMitjans, you should change the title of this question to something like "UI-Rating Directive changeable max value" or something. The current title might not be helpful for people with a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

I've just quickly looked over this problem and it seems like the AngularJS Bootstrap Rating directive doesn't handle updating the max value on the fly.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to wrap your own rating directive for this. Otherwise either monkey-patch their code, make a Pull Request for this issue, or report the issue and fiddle with your thumbs.


EDIT: Also on how to do it you might want to take a look at how they did it. 

[rating.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/rating/rating.js)
[rating.html](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/rating/rating.html)

Comment: Hi Mike,

I redid it using this example: http://www.befundoo.com/university/tutorials/angularjs-directives-tutorial/

The rating system works flawlessly, buuut, same problem updating the star variable on the fly. 

You can see the new Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/nYQ2lbq0O0ecXOEB20vK?p=preview What else could it be? Somehow I'm binding it one-way (variable -> input), but not the other way around...

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found another hack for this:

Wrapping your rating-directive in a ng-if also seems to work.

```
<div ng-if="true">
  <rating max="myVar"></rating>
</div>
```

According to the angular documentation, ng-if will reinsert the HTML on each evaluation, triggering a re-evaluation of `myVar`.

Yes, it is still a bit hacky, but I think it is prettier than changing code in your bower_components-folder which will be overwritter on each update.